# How to display files from a folder in django

Tags: html, django, file, file-upload

I have made a django app that has images in a folder.I have to create a dropdown menu as to which image it has to select.One has to provide the path to the folder and this image should be displayed on the html page.

Answer (score 0):

The questions is somewhat modified version of:
[Django: Auto-generating a list of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7042031/6284117)

(Credits: @Hoff for accepted answer to above mentioned post):

Bit of code:

views.py

```
import os 

def gallery(request):
    path="C:\\somedirectory"  # insert the path to your directory   
    img_list =os.listdir(path)   
    return render_to_response('gallery.html', {'images': img_list})
```

gallery.html

```
{% for image in images %}
<img src='/static/{{image}}' />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of Fakkabir’s answer and an assumption that the images you’re trying to load are available via /static/

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os 

def gallery(request):
    path="C:\\somedirectory"  # insert the path to your directory   
    img_list =os.listdir(path)   
    return render(request, 'gallery.html', {'images': img_list})
```

gallery.html

```
{% load static %}

{% for image in images %}
    <img src= '{% static image %}'>
{% endfor %}
```